# Print all the coordinates of points between two points in Python

Tags: python

i need all the coordinates of points between two points with one decimal point

like :

the input :
point1(1,2) , point2(0,0)

the output :
(0.1,0.2)
(0.2,0.4)
(0.3,0.6)
(0.4,0.8)
(0.5,1)
(0.6,1.2)
(0.7,1.4)
(0.8,1.6)
(0.9,1.8)
(1,2)

thanks all for the help

Comment: it is not clear, what you are asking.

Comment: I suppose you will get many downvote due to lack of what you have tried so far. Please edit the question and show what you have tried of your own.

Comment: What should be produced for input `point1(0,0), point2(1,1.1)`?  Or `point1(0,0), point2(0.5, 0.75)`?

Comment: The increment on `x` axis is 0.1 but on `y` axis is 0.2. So, what do you mean by `one decimal point`?

Answer (score 0):

I think a simpler solution in this case is to add 0.1 to the minimum value of each point while it is lower than the maximum (target value).

Answer (score -2):

Considering you want 10 intermediate points you can make:

```
def get_intermediary_points(p1, p2, number):
    p = [p1]
    dx = abs(p1[0] - p2[0])
    dy = abs(p1[1] - p2[1])
    for inter in range(1, num):
        p.append( (dx/num * inter, dy/num * inter) )
    p.append(p2)
    return p 

p1 = (1,2)
p2 = (0,0)
get_intermediary_points(p1, p2, 10)
```

The above code divide distance between the two in 10 and add a little bit at every iteration

Comment: "...with one decimal point"